# Handling SMS messages when processing forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, twilio

I have a few views which handle the forms for new objects being created which seem to lag the user experience due to having to connect to the Twilio API. For example, the following `form_valid` method sends an SMS message to all receivers of a memo:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.sender = self.request.user
        form.save()
        receiving_groups = form.cleaned_data['receiver']

        for group in receiving_groups:
            username = list(
                employees.models.Employee.objects.filter(
                    employee_type=group))
            for user in username:
                form.instance.unread.add(user)
                memo_url = form.instance.pk
                user.send_sms('memo', memo_url)
                user.send_email('memo', memo_url)

        form.save()
        return super(MemoCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The issue here is that the `send_sms` method has to wait for a response before continuing. This really makes the site seem slow to the user.

I have started to create a `request_finished` signal but I would have to pass **a lot** of parameters to the signal so this seems like a bad option.

What other options do I have for sending the SMS messages post-success/redirect of the object being created?

Comment: I think your only option is sending the task to a background worker. using `celery` or some other task queue tool

Comment: I have heard of `celery` but never looked into it. It seems this is exactly what i need. Thank you for your help!